# Updating values in a table based on the inner join of two other tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's the scenario:

```
TABLE 1 (client table. imported into sql server via a csv file)
column 1    column2
Cust ID      value

TABLE 2 (my table)
column 1    column2
Record ID    value


TABLE 3 (my table)
column 1    column2
Record ID   Cust ID
```

How do I update "value"/column 2 in table 2, given the "value" in table 1 that has only Cust ID (and not Record ID)?

I know some kind of join has to happen with tables 2 and 3, but how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Provide some example what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Update TableTwo
set TableTwo.column2 = TableOne.column2
FROM TableOne 
Join TableThree on TableOne.column1 = TableThree.column2
Join TableTwo on TableTwo.column1 = TableThree.column1
```

Basically that is it.

You can refer to [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177523%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).